# Export pictures from Delphi cxGrid(or just from cxImage) to Excel

Tags: excel, delphi, devexpress, vcl, tcxgrid

I have task to export cxGrids with pictures from different forms of Delphi app. Now for exporting picture I use clipboard by following way `Clipboard.Assign(Picture)`, then I select column and use method `Excel.Selection.PasteSpecial` for pasting picture from clipboard.
But seems that this way is not such fast as I need. And maybe do you know other ways to export image from Delphi app to Excel?

Comment: Beside the clipboard, I only see one other possibility: save the picture on disk and make Excel load the file from there. It will be probably be slower because clipboard is an in-memory process while using the disk involves...a disk which is always slower.